# Let A means B in math logic.

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I am learning Math Logics to greatly reduce usage of words when defining patterns in math.

Currently I know what some basic signs means like $\implies$, $\iff$, $\forall$, $\exists$, $\exists!$, $:$, $:=$, etc.

Unfortunately couldn't find how to represent new ideas like "let A menas B". 
Does such convetions exist ?

For example I would like to write : 
Let $ B = f(A) $ means $B = \{ \forall a \in A : f(a) \}$, 
where $A, B$ are sets, and $f$ is a function.

Can it be done as $B = f(A) \iff B = \{ \forall a \in A : f(a) \}$, or it's incorrect approach ?

---

EDIT $1$

After long day of learning math symbols I am close to believe that it's the correct notation :

$(B = f(A)) := (B = \{ b = f(a) : \forall a \in A \}$)

The reason is :
$:=$ means 'A is defined by B' so by it it's clear what I mean by suing set as a parameter to function

Please correct me if it's wrong.

Comment: Set $E$ is compact $\iff$ every open cover of $E$ has a finite subcover. Definitions imply an if and only if statement.

Comment: @Michal Re: your original suggestion using $'\iff'$, other than the fact that the statement fails to convey that a definition (as opposed to a deduction) is being made, the middleman $'B'$ is a redundant diversion as the intended definition now implicitly seems to require the transitivity of $'='$ and on the implication $[C,D]\ne B{\implies}C\ne D.$ If the goal is genuinely to maximise the notation:words ratio (which may not maximise clarity), then David's suggestion $f(A) := \{ \forall a \in A : f(a) \}$ is (naturally) the most straightforward way to *define the notation $f(A).$*

Comment: See [Definitions](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend very strong against the notation in "EDIT $1$".
The "$:=$" symbol is really just "$=$" with an extra meaning.
When we write "$\text{_____} := \text{_____}$", filling in the blank spaces on each side with something appropriate, we mean that the thing on the left *is equal to* the thing on the right *by definition*.

It's fine to say that a certain expression expressing a quantity is equal to another,
but an equation does not express a quantity and it is not a good idea to
set one equation "equal" to another equation.

In many cases, the correct mathematical notation for a statement is **no notation**.
Here, for example, you could say,

> We write $ B = f(A) $ if $B = \{ \forall a \in A : f(a) \}$.

---

The real problem with what you are trying to write, however, appears to be the use of the symbol $B$.
When we write $B = f(A),$ there had better be no doubt about what the "$=$" symbol signifies: it says that whatever $B$ represents is exactly the same thing as whatever $f(A)$ represents.

What you actually seem to need to express in this case is, what exactly **is** the thing that $f(A)$ is meant to represent?
That is, in order to say what $B = f(A)$ means, what you really need to do is just to describe what $f(A)$ means. That is, you need to define the notation "$f(A)$".

It seems that $A$ is intended to be a set in this particular context and $f$ is meant to be the name of a function.
You could then define $f(A)$ like this:

> For a set $A$ and a function $f: A\to X,$
> $$ f(A) := \{ \forall a \in A : f(a) \}.$$

That's how the symbol "$:=$" can be used.